# R oce - How to apply read.topo or as.topo to .xyz file from ETOPO1

Tags: r, mapping, topology

I really like the oce package and would like to use plot.topo to make a map of the coastline and bathymetry of Eastern Canada and Northeastern United States. I am trying to make a dataset like "topoMaritimes", which is available and covers much of my study area, but I need Newfoundland/Labrador and New England, USA to be included as well.

I tried using the worldCoastline dataset but the resolution is too low.

I obtained a .xyz dataset from ETOPO1 from my study area (using the same source as the oce creator: http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/gdas/gd_designagrid.html), which should work for me. I am now trying to read it into R using read.topo() or as.topo() but have run into problems.

I assumed read.topo() would work, given the info specified here: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/oce/docs/read.topo.  But when I use read.topo:

```
geo<-read.topo("ETOPO1data.xyz")
Error in if (is.character(file) && grep(".nc$", file)) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Apparently this error indicates that there are missing values/NAs?

When I try importing it as a generic text file, it works:

```
geo<-read.table(file="ETOPO1data.xyz", sep="")

head(geo)
           V1         V2  V3
1 -73.000000, 56.000000, 331
2 -72.983333, 56.000000, 328
3 -72.966667, 56.000000, 327
4 -72.950000, 56.000000, 327
5 -72.933333, 56.000000, 325
6 -72.916667, 56.000000, 324
```

However, when I try to coerce this into a "topo" type of object, I get an error:

```
geo<-as.topo(geo$V1, geo$V2, geo$V3)
Error in Summary.factor(c(1261L, 1260L, 1259L, 1258L, 1257L, 1256L, 1255L,  : 
min not meaningful for factors
```

As it turns out, the longitude and latitude fields are factors:

```
str(geo)
'data.frame':   1211821 obs. of  3 variables:
$ V1: Factor w/ 1261 levels "-52.000000,",..: 1261 1260 1259 1258 1257 1256 1255 1254         1253 1252 ...
$ V2: Factor w/ 961 levels "40.000000,","40.016667,",..: 961 961 961 961 961 961 961 961 961 961 ...
$ V3: int  331 328 327 327 325 324 325 329 336 351 ...
```

However, converting the lats/lons to numeric type changes their values completely:

```
geo$V1<-as.numeric(geo$V1)
geo$V2<-as.numeric(geo$V2)
head(geo)
V1  V2  V3
1 1261 961 331
2 1260 961 328
3 1259 961 327
4 1258 961 327
5 1257 961 325
6 1256 961 324
```

Anyone know how to convert an x/y/z (i.e. lon/lat/depth) file to a "topo" object? Could it be an issue caused by me using ETOPO1 instead of ETOPO2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using raster but use the netcdf files. Those files have problems and I always recreate them as respectable Geotiffs. I will detail this out but not right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the marmap package.

`library(marmap)
 papoue <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = 140, lon2 = 155, lat1 = -13, lat2 = 0,
                resolution = 10)
 summary(papoue)
blues <- colorRampPalette(c("red","purple","blue","cadetblue1",
                   "white"))`

You can convert between data types using `as.xyz` and `as.bathy`

`plot(papoue, image = TRUE, bpal = blues(100))`